# Loss of precision using arrays and long data types

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, long-integer, type-conversion

This is a program designed to estimate the value of pi using Buffons needle simulation. The problem I am having here is that if the user inputs a really big number, the program crashes. I'm assuming it's because I am not using a long data type instead of the int. When I tried to change the number of trials in the trials method to a long data type, it kept giving me an error saying that there was a lack of precision for the length of the array. I can't figure out how to fix this problem.. Help?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Darts
{
    public static long trials() //User Inputs number of trials
    {
        long input;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many darts/trials? ");
        input = in.nextLong();

        return input;
    }

    public static double [] randomX(long trial) // Randomly generates numbers for the x coordinate on the amounts of trials

    {
        double [] randNumArrayX = new double[trial];
        for(int i = 0; i < trial; i++)
        {
            randNumArrayX[i] = Math.random();
        }
        return randNumArrayX;
    }

    public static double [] randomY(long trial) // Randomly generates numbers forthe y coordinate on the amounts of trials
    {
        double [] randNumArrayY = new double[trial];
        for(int i = 0; i < trial; i++)
        {
            randNumArrayY[i] = Math.random();
        }
        return randNumArrayY;
    }

    public static int [] dartBoard(double [] randx, double [] randy) // determines whether the dark hit the board or not
    {
        int [] hitMiss = new int[randx.length];
        int [] trials = new int[randx.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < randx.length; i++)
        {
            if( Math.pow(randx[i] , 2) + Math.pow(randy[i] , 2) <= 1)
            {
                hitMiss[i] = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                hitMiss[i] = 0;
            }
        }
        return hitMiss;
    }

    public static double [] calcPi(int [] h) // Calculates pi using randomly generated numbers
    {
        int hitCounter = 0;
        double [] pi = new double[h.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < h.length; i++)
        {
            if(h[i] == 1)
            {
                hitCounter++;
            }
            pi[i] = 4*(hitCounter/(i + 1));
        }
        return pi;
    }

    public static void print(double [] pi) // prints results
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%-7s%2d%-8s%-10.6f%n", "Trial [", i, "]: pi = ", pi[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("\t   .....");
        System.out.printf("%-17s%-10.6f%n", "Estimate of pi = ", pi[pi.length -1]);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) // main method
    {
        long t = trials();
        double [] x = new double[t];
        double [] y = new double[t];
        int [] h = new int[t];
        double [] p = new double[t];
        x = randomX(t);
        y = randomY(t);
        h = dartBoard( x , y );
        p = calcPi( h );
        print(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot create arrays larger than 2 billion in Java, because you have to use an int for an array's size, and you just changed it to a long.

Comment: @Keppil Give this to `javac`: `(new int[2])[1L] = 1;` The error is "possible loss of precision".

Comment: you can't pass long value as array length

Comment: @Marko: Eclipse gives me another error: _Type mismatch: cannot convert from long to int_.

Comment: @Keppil Have you noticed that Eclipse has entirely different error messages than `javac`? And much more useful---this one being a very good case in point.

Comment: @Marko: No need for that tone, I am merely noting that Eclipse gives another error.

Comment: @Keppil Sorry about the apparently dismissive tone, I wasn't going for it. I am a bit unfocused at the moment... I rephrased, hopefully it doesn't sound harsh now.

Answer (score 0):

Size of an array must be in **int,char or expression that generate result of int or char**.

```
long t = trials();
    double [] x = new double[t];
```

Here your are using long.